# How do I run/install Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: tar

I got ubuntutouch 14.10 download
the file format is Tar.gz
How can I install this file?
When I extract it to a folder that contains 1.5 GB of built

[image: Screenshot]

These folders are exactly like Ubuntu folders in the root folder

Since this is a file that I've downloaded to PC's, then there should be a way for him to run.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: @JorgeCastro Not sure that applies here. I think the question is actually "How do I run/install Ubuntu Touch?"

Answer (score 1):

**Unzip**

```
tar -xzvf CatlateralDamage_v4.1a_linux.tar.gz
```

**Install step :**(execute from program folder)

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello.
Thank you very much for your answer
But this command to install the programs.
This folder is exactly folder preinstalled on Ubuntu
Does not compile

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a compressed system image. If you want you can restore it to a disk like a full system, following this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR

Comment: Hello.
Thank you very much for your answer
This guide is for Kubuntu?
I only backup in Ubuntu